# Firebase Hosting (Angular 8 + Service Worker) not updating on a refresh

Tags: angular, firebase, service-worker, firebase-hosting, angular-universal

I own [quackr.io](https://quackr.io) and have run into some trouble with users not seeing the new version of my code.  quackr is a PWA (Angular SSR + Service worker) deployed onto Firebase hosting.

Whenever I deploy a new version, anyone who has viewed the site previously will see the old version.  If you do a hard refresh you will see the new version.  However if you do another normal page refresh it will revert back to the old version.

- Page refresh: Receive old version
- Hard refresh: Receive new version (but get the old version as soon as i do a normal refresh again)
- Unregister service worker in chrome and do a normal refresh: Receive new version (but also get the old version as soon as i do a second refresh).
- I've cleared all browser cache, cookies & storage. Again, this works for the initial refresh but not any subsequent ones.

Here's my firebase.json (i was hoping adding no-cache to the service worker js it would invalidate upon deploying but it didn't work):

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist/browser",
    "headers": [
    {
      "source": "/@(ngsw-worker.js|ngsw.json)",
      "headers": [
        {
          "key": "Cache-Control",
          "value": "no-cache"
        }
      ]
  } 
  ],
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "ssr"
      }
    ]
  },
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
    ]
  }
}
```

ngsw-config.json:

```
{
  "index": "/index.html",
  "appData": {
    "name": "quackr.io",
    "description": "v2.0"
  },
  "assetGroups": [{
    "name": "app",
    "installMode": "prefetch",
    "resources": {
      "files": [
        "/favicon.ico",
        "/index.html",
        "/*.css",
        "/*.js"
      ]
    }
  }, {
    "name": "assets",
    "installMode": "lazy",
    "updateMode": "prefetch",
    "resources": {
      "files": [
        "/assets/**"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "fonts",
    "resources": {
      "urls": [
        "https://fonts.googleapis.com/**"
      ]
    }
  }]
}
```

https://quackr.io/ngsw-worker.js

Any help would be appreciated, thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use Angular's service worker update functionality, which will watch for any new changes in the app, and then either refresh the page or notify the user about the updates and give them the option to refresh themselves:

see this example:

```
constructor(
        private swUpdate: SwUpdate,
        private snackbar: MatSnackBar
    ) {
        this.swUpdate.available.subscribe(evt => {
            const snack: any = this.snackbar.open(`Updates Available`, 'Reload');

            snack.onAction().subscribe(() => {
                window.location.reload();
            });

            snack.setTimeout(() => {
                snack.dismiss();
            }, 6000);
        });
    }
```

Original Docs:
https://angular.io/api/service-worker/SwUpdate

More info:
https://alligator.io/angular/service-worker-updates/

Here is my Firebase.json file

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist/myApp",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "**/*.@(eot|otf|ttf|ttc|woff|woff2|font.css)",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
            "value": "max-age=31557600"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "source": "**/*.@(js|css)",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "max-age=31557600"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "source": "**/*.@(svg|ico|json|mp3)",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "max-age=31557600"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "ssr"
      }
    ]
  },
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix %RESOURCE_DIR% run lint",
      "npm --prefix %RESOURCE_DIR% run build"
    ],
    "source": "functions"
  },
  "emulators": {
    "functions": {
      "port": "5005"
    }
  },
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Nadhir!

This doesnt fix my issue unfortunately.  Even with subscribing to service worker changes, whenever window.location.reload() is invoked it reloads and still picks up the old version of the app.

Comment: why did you need this: "headers": [
    {
      "source": "/@(ngsw-worker.js|ngsw.json)",
      "headers": [
        {
          "key": "Cache-Control",
          "value": "no-cache"
        }
      ]

Comment: I don't think you need firebase hosting to cache the service worker for you

Comment: I did some research and thought this might solve my problem by not caching the service worker js, so upon a refresh it would pick up the latest and register it. It didn't work though!

Comment: I'm using firebase and Angular SW, I posted what I had for refreshing the sw, and I will post my firebase.json file for you so you can compare

Comment: pay attention to this part `"source": "**/*.@(js|css)",`